# Facebook API - get a user's page subscriptions?

Tags: facebook, api, subscriptions

Does anyone know if there is a way to get the page subscriptions of a Facebook user? Does there exist any alternative for the old, removed `user_subscriptions` permission?

Answer (score 0):

No, this has been deprecated since Graph API v2.0, and there's no alternative to it.

See

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_0